# Linq to Entities DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF 4 to PostgreSQL using a 3rd party ADO.NET provider.  In my data source, I have no item lines that match items based on this join condition.  For this reason I expect query 1 to fail based on a null reference exception.  However, it completes and gives me value type defaults for each of the properties on il. item_display_name is a string so ilName is set to null.  ilStartDate is set to DateTime's default.  x.il.item_id and x.il.item_line_no are both 0.

```
var query1 =
                    _db.items
                      .GroupJoin(_db.item_line.Where(x => x.start_date == selectedStartDate), x => x.item_id, il => il.item_id, (x, ilgroup) => new { x, ilgroup })
                      .SelectMany(x => x.ilgroup.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, il) => new { x.x, il })
                      .Select(x =>
                          new
                              {
                                    itemId = x.x.item_id,
                                    ilName = x.il.item_display_name,
                                    ilStartDate = x.il.start_date,
                                    ilItemId = x.il.item_id,
                                    orderLine = x.il.item_line_no});
```

However, if I force execution by calling ToArray on my results before the Select, I then get my null reference exception.

```
var query2 =
                _db.items
                    .GroupJoin(_db.item_line.Where(x => x.start_date == selectedStartDate), x => x.item_id, il => il.item_id, (x, ilgroup) => new {x, ilgroup})
                    .SelectMany(x => x.ilgroup.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, il) => new {x.x, il}).ToArray()
                    .Select(x =>
                            new
                                {
                                    itemId = x.x.item_id,
                                    ilName = x.il.item_display_name,
                                    ilStartDate = x.il.start_date,
                                    ilItemId = x.il.item_id,
                                    orderLine = x.il.item_line_no});
```

To my understanding, DefaultIfEmpty should return the default for that type.  My type is clearly a reference type, so why won't query 1 fail?

Comment: query1 is being translated completely to SQL. You're not going to get an NRE in SQL, but check the generated SQL to learn specifically what it is doing. query2 is performing additional work in memory, and a null result is going to therefore be problematic if you do not account for it.

Comment: What code is executing after the query? Are you accessing the results in any way? Since LINQ uses delayed execution, you need to access the results in order for the query to actually execute. Calling `ToArray()` in `query2` is making the execution happen - if you do nothing with `query1` after what you've posted, it will never execute!

Comment: @AnthonyPegram:  Of course! It seems so simple when you put it like that.  I the database would want to return a null there, but because the ints and DateTime are not nullable, EF has to put something in there.  Your comment explains away the confusion.  You should move it to an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the first query is completely translated into SQL. SQL is different than C# when it comes to null "objects". In SQL it is perfectly OK to write something like

```sql
SELECT o.Date, ol.Number FROM Order o LEFT JOIN OrderLine ol ON ... (etc.)
```

It won't crash when there are `Order`s without `OrderLine`s. No null reference exception on `ol` here. SQL just outputs null values for `ol.Number` where order lines are missing.

So in the **first** statement the anonymous type is built directly from values obtained from SQL. The whole expression `x.il.item_display_name` is populated by output from a `DbDataReader`, which is null when no `ilgroup` is present.

In the **second** statement, first an array of objects is built in memory, consisting of `x` and `il` pairs, some which have no `il` (`il` is null). Now the anonymous type is built from the object array and the expression `x.il.item_display_name` tries to read `item_display_name` from some non-existing objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky characteristic of the Entity Framework. When you are doing the whole query, you don't actually hit the database. EF will only go to the database when you do a ToArray, ToList, etc...

In the first query, you should get the NullReference if you put the ToArray() at the end. While you don't actually do a ToArray, you'll be only constructing the query to run when you do the ToList(), or ToArray().

Take a look at this post: [Am I hitting the database?](http://www.singingeels.com/Blogs/Nullable/2008/08/04/LINQ_to_SQL__Am_I_Hitting_The_Database.aspx)